# How To Stop setTimeout() That Has Already Fired

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering how would I stop a setTimeout() that has already started? In my example below I have two buttons: `.start` and `.cancel`. Pressing `.start` would invoke the timer which will execute a `console.log()` after 2 seconds. I am trying to get the behavior where clicking `.cancel` would stop the timer from executing and to clear its queue. Is this possible?

The issue I am experiencing is that if I click on `.start`, and then immediately click on `.cancel` before the 2 second, I will still see `btn clicked` in the console. I do not want to see that console message.

```
var timer;

$('.start').on('mousedown', function() {
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('btn clicked');
  }, 2000);
});

$('.cancel').on('mousedown', function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xL8yquoL/

Comment: Works just like you said for me... What problem are you *actually* experiencing?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have just updated my post to answer your question

Comment: Works as described, what browser are you using ?

Comment: @Jon I do not experience that in Chrome 51.0.2704.103 nor Internet Explorer Edge.

Comment: Is your issue with _multiple_ timers, because this only cancels the last one?

Comment: Odd, it is working for me now too!

Comment: @joews How would I cancel multiple timers? I may need to know this for the future

Comment: @jon just keep an array of timers

Comment: Cool, thanks :) Let me close this post.

Answer (score 3):

Your code cancels a single timer, but you could create several by clicking "start" many times.

If you need to cancel several timers you could keep an array of timer references.

In this example, each `.cancel` click clears the *last* timer created, because `array.pop` removes and returns the last item in `array`.

```
var timers = [];

$('.start').on('mousedown', function() {
  timers.push(setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('btn clicked');
  }, 2000));
});

$('.cancel').on('mousedown', function() {
  clearTimeout(timers.pop());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xL8yquoL/1/

If you need to clear *every* timer with one click:

```
$('.cancel').on('mousedown', function() {
  timers.forEach(clearTimeout)

  timers = [];
});
```

Comment: Well, this code still only cancels a single timer per click, no?

Comment: It does. I've added some code to clear them all, too.

Comment: If you want for there to only ever be one timer at once, you could set `timer` to `null` when it is cleared or finished, and then assign with `timer = timer || setTimeout;`

Comment: More likely, the start button should clear the existing timer before starting it again.